# Laravel 9 install error: PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version on Windows

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I installed Xampp version 3.3.0 which supports PHP 8.1 and composer version 2.3.5. When I change directory to `htdocs` directory of the xampp, and write

> composer create-project laravel/laravel="9.*"

It reports error

```
Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 9.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.
```

The fileinfo extension is installed.

I should note that there is also an old version of xampp but I started the server of new Xampp

Comment: Run `php -v` to show your PHP version, you're probably still running the old.

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes you are right. version 7 is running. How can I switch to 8?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with XAMPP but... just uninstall 7?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I just double clicked on the `setup_xampp.bat` file and all is fine now